# bootbox modal not setting 'selected' select list item

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, selectlist, bootbox

I have a form inside a bootbox modal thats populated via and ajax call to an mvc controller action.  The form is correctly populated with the underlying data but im not able to set the selected item in a select list.

In my diaglog.init function I populate the form element like this

```js
dialog.init(function () {
                        var frm = document.querySelector("#userForm");
                        
                        if ("NewUser_UserRole" in frm.elements) {
                            frm.elements["NewUser_UserRole"].value = data.UserRole;
                            
                        }
                        if ("NewUser_Status" in frm.elements) {
                            frm.elements["NewUser_Status"].value = data.Status;
                            
                        }
                                               
                        $(".modal .modal-dialog").attr("class", "modal-dialog zoomIn animated");
                        $("#userForm").show();// Show the data entry form
                    });
```

this works as expected except that the select list item 'selected' value does not match the value retrieved from the database, so I added some code here

```js
.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                        
                        $('#NewUser_UserRole').val($.trim(data.UserRole)).prop('selected', true);
                        $('#NewUser_Status').val($.trim(data.Status)).prop('selected', true);
                    })
```

when I open the modal popup, the selected item is still not the value from the database, yet when I hit the 'refresh' button on the browser and try it again, it works.  If I open up a new data record, its remembers the previous selection, so I have to hit 'refresh' again for it to work.  Can anyone tell me whats happening here ?  Surely this should work each time I load a new item from the database

Comment: If NewUser_UserRole and NewUser_Status are select elements, setting the the selected property does nothing - that's only valid on the `<option>` element. You _could_ do something like `$('#NewUser_UserRole').val($.trim(data.UserRole)).trigger('change')` if you want to trigger the change event on your select. `init` is also only really called once, when the bootbox object is created, so you're probably better off moving all of your code to the `shown.bs.modal` event.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you